# Unable to map docker volume with colon

Tags: docker, mount

Is there a way to mount a host directory as a data volume while the host directory path contains a colon?
Example

```
-v /colon:path/test:data
```

In that case it's treating `data` as additional option. The `/colon:path/test` is a correct Unix path.

Comment: Looks like a bug / edge case to me. Suggest you file an issue :)

Comment: Follow this bug: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8604

Comment: I wonder what happens if you create a symbolic link and map it instead of the colon dir. `ln -s /colon:path /nocolonpath`

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  With the `--mount` option you can specify the source and destination.  This option was added to Docker 17.05.0.

```
--mount type=bind,source=/colon:path/test,destination=/data
```

Note: You must use absolute pathnames.  I'm assuming the destination is /data.

From the [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) manpage:

> See also --mount, which is the successor of --tmpfs and --volume. 
>   Even though there is no plan to deprecate --volume, usage of --mount
>   is recommended.

Example:

```
touch foo:bar
docker run --rm --mount type=bind,source=$PWD/foo:bar,destination=/tmp/foo:bar busybox ls /tmp
```

Comment: This is the option for `docker service create` and I'm not using docker swarm mode.

Comment: This is the option to docker run.  Check the manpage in the link above.

Comment: Curious how do you escape `,destination=...`  if your path ends with that?
(obviously, this is a security issue somewhere)

Comment: @jonasfj Seems like one can do [CSV-escaping](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8604#issuecomment-505415519). However, I doubt that this is documentend anywhere ...