# How to escape colon when add device to docker container?

Tags: docker

1. This is ok to add device which by serial id:

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --device /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A101A9A7-if00-port0 -v /dev:/dev ubuntu /bin/bash
   ```
2. This is not ok to add device which by serial path:

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --device /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:8:1.0-port0 -v /dev:/dev ubuntu /bin/bash
   ```

   It reports error:

   > invalid argument "/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:8:1.0-port0" for "--device" flag: bad format for path: /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:8:1.0-port0
   >   See 'docker run --help'.

   Same error if do escape string for `:` as next:

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --device /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000\:00\:14.0-usb-0\:8\:1.0-port0 -v /dev:/dev ubuntu /bin/bash
   ```

As I know, for `bind mount`, we now could use something like `--mount type=bind,source=/colon:path/test,destination=/data` to handle it, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938108/unable-to-map-docker-volume-with-colon).

So my question is: for `--device`, what could I do?

Comment: Did you try to use single quotes around device name ? like this : 
```docker run -it --rm --device '/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:8:1.0-port0' -v /dev:/dev ubuntu /bin/bash```

Comment: @Flo Not work with `''`, also not with `""`

Comment: Ah! You're not alone, check last answer: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8604#issuecomment-451705509 
I don't know if it's an open issue or not...

Comment: Seems no one handle that, half year ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for myself, from [this discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8604):

It seems CLI not support escaping the colons, currently the only way is to make symbol link like next:

```
ln -s /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:8:1.0-port0 /dev/serial/by-path/mydevice01
docker run -it --rm --device /dev/serial/by-path/mydevice01 -v /dev:/dev ubuntu /bin/bash
```

This is what I made workaround currently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the situation with docker is of course awful. So much for the tool which runs the industry...